# Validating content on Oracle API Gateway

Tags: java, oracle, api-gateway

I am quite new to Oracle API Gateway and I need to have access to all its fields in order to make validation. Thus, I am using a small Java application I developed with Entity(getAllFields) and EntityStore(findChildren). However, the fields name that I am getting don't correspond to those visible to the GUI on Oracle API Gateway. So, for example, if I want to validate that the collection's name cannot have more than 48 characters, I don't know how to do it.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.